# FB duplicate App ID

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

I registered an app with FB and was using the APP ID (API key) to let users log in using FB from both web and a mobile app and everything was working fine. Till we started seeing some intermittent failures - we would still get an access token from FB, but couldn't use it **sometimes** (would get 400 - Error validating access token: Session is invalid"). When I went to FB app settings page, I noticed the APP ID has changed from what we were using. Weird, cause I am not sure how it changed. Anyway we tried to use the new API ID and it workes fine, but the old also works - at least sometimes.

Any one have a clue what is going on? TIA